# Can't login after entering correct username and password

Tags: 18.04, username

I wanted to change the name before hostname on my Ubuntu terminal (the `x` in `x@y` )
To do so I replaced old `x` in `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow` with newname

Now when I am trying to open Ubuntu, its not opening up; it is redirecting me to lock screen

Comment: What could be a possible solution now?

Comment: Even If I enter my new username and password...it's showing the same results...black screen and then back to lock screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because a username mustn't be change manually (it's not about just changing username inside `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow` files); the `/home` directory wasn't created, so it didn't find where it can login, and finally return to the login screen in order to say at user that he must fix this issue. Here are differents ways to fix that :

- Connect using `tty` console :

  1. use the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> to open the `tty` terminal
  2. try to login -> if it didn't work, try login with root access
  3. revert change in `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow` files
  4. after revert are effected, use `sudo usermod -l newUsername oldUsername` command to change the old username `oldUsername` with a new one `newUsername` **everywhere** needed
  5. logout / reboot, you can return to GUI using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>
- If you can't connect to a login using the `tty` console

  1. reboot your computer and start Ubuntu in recovery mode (or command line mode *don't know exactly how it is named*)
  2. revert change in `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow` files
  3. after revert are effected, use `sudo usermod -l newUsername oldUsername` command to change the old username `oldUsername` with a new one `newUsername` **everywhere** needed
  4. reboot your computer
- If no one of these methods works, then you can try to restore username by using a live session

  1. use this following commands to mount your partition :

     ```
     sudo fdisk -l    ###find the partition which contains your data

     sudo mount /dev/sdaN /mnt  ####N is the partition number (can be sdbN, sdcN too)
     sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
     sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
     sudo mount --bind /run  /mnt/run
     sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
     sudo chroot /mnt           ####after this command, you re inside your previous Ubuntu partition
     ```
  2. revert change in `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow` files
  3. after revert are effected, use `sudo usermod -l newUsername oldUsername` command to change the old username `oldUsername` with a new one `newUsername` **everywhere** needed
  4. reboot your computer

If no one of these methods works (I really doubt), I couldn't help more

Comment: When I trying the first method....firstly it's not accepting my old username...it's accepting the new username...but when I try to use sudo to revert back the contents of a read-only file..it's says that new username is not a part of sudoers file

Comment: The second method worked...thank you very much

Comment: Just one question if any1 can change settings in recovery mode then how is it safe?

Comment: that's a really good question, I recomment you to post it (before do a few search on it), I don't know how to answer about that (because I don't have enough knowledge about recovery mode)

Comment: Will surely post this...Anyways thankyou very much for help

Comment: What should I do to correctly change username?

Comment: see the point `3.` of method 2/3 (point `4.` for method 1), use `sudo usermod -l newUsername oldUsername` command

Comment: Recovery mode is considered `safe` as when somebody has physical access to a pc it is always possible to mount the hard drive with a live system or remove the hd and take it away.

Answer (score 0):

Both `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow` are not meant to be edited manually / with a text editor.

This won't help you much, but in order to change your username you should have used the `usermod` command.

I can think of two possible solutions:

1. If you have another user on your system, log in, and revert the changes you did on both mentioned files.
2. Use a bootable medium, like an USB stick or a CD-ROM with Linux, boot your PC and mount the hard drive of your installed Linux. Then revert the changes.

Comment: No I don't have any other account...I will have to prepare a bootable pendrive to go for the second solution....Can you think of any other solution? I even tried going to console and undoing the changes that I did but it's showing that my new_username is not a part of sudoers...